# Find Difficulty in Generating a Subgraph DAG using Graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot

I am using graphviz (version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304)) to convert a program-generated dot file to a png. Basically what I want to visualize by the dot file is a subgraph directed acyclic graph, i.e., subgraph DAG in short, where each node of the DAG is a subgraph. For the visualization, I need to present (1) the structure of the DAG; and (2) the topology of the subgraph of each DAG node.

For example, the following dot file generates the following png, where there are 3 DAG nodes and 2 DAG edges. I use `cluster` to represent the subgraph of each DAG node. I think it's still readable to human.

```
digraph plan_v1 {
  rankdir=LR
  compound=true
  subgraph cluster28 {
    color=black // not query
    shape=box
    penwidth=3
    label="id: 28\ndag id: 0\ncardinality: 100"
    {
      rank=min
      28.0 [shape=box label="id: 0\nlabel: 0"]
      28.1 [shape=box label="id: 1\nlabel: 0"]
    }
    28.0 -> 28.1 [label="label: 0"]
  }
  subgraph cluster29 {
    color=black // not query
    shape=box
    penwidth=3
    label="id: 29\ndag id: 1\ncardinality: 301"
    {
      rank=min
      29.0 [shape=box label="id: 0\nlabel: 0"]
      29.1 [shape=box label="id: 1\nlabel: 0"]
    }
    {
      rank=max
      29.2 [shape=box label="id: 2\nlabel: 0"]
    }
    29.0 -> 29.1 [label="label: 0"]
    29.0 -> 29.2 [label="label: 0"]
    29.1 -> 29.2 [label="label: 0"]
  }
  28.1 -> 29.0 [ltail=cluster28 lhead=cluster29 penwidth=1 minlen=2 label="latency: 0\ncost: 0\npath cost: 0\nsub tree cost: 479"]
  subgraph cluster15 {
    color=black // not query
    shape=box
    penwidth=3
    label="id: 15\ndag id: 2\ncardinality: 376"
    {
      rank=min
      15.0 [shape=box label="id: 0\nlabel: 0"]
      15.1 [shape=box label="id: 1\nlabel: 0"]
    }
    {
      rank=max
      15.2 [shape=box label="id: 2\nlabel: 0"]
    }
    15.0 -> 15.1 [label="label: 0"]
    15.0 -> 15.2 [label="label: 0"]
    15.2 -> 15.1 [label="label: 0"]
  }
  28.1 -> 15.0 [ltail=cluster28 lhead=cluster15 penwidth=1 minlen=2 label="latency: 0\ncost: 0\npath cost: 0\nsub tree cost: 2319"]
}
```

[image: subgraph dag example]

The problem is, when the number of vertices of the subgraph increases, graphviz uses large space to represent each DAG node that has a large subgraph. I want to reduce the space for large subgraph by controlling the layout of the subgraph vertices. Basically my strategy is, given a subgraph with `n` vertices, I give `min` rank to vertex id `0` and `1`, `max` rank to vertex id `n-1` and `n-2`, and I request the rank of vertex `2*i` and `2*i+1` to be the `same` for `0<i<(n-1)/2`. Forget to tell that I am a beginner of graphviz so there could be mistake for the design of the above strategy (but not implementation).

With the above strategy, I found that graphviz may not be able to generate png if the subgraph DAG is too complex. Here is an example: https://gist.github.com/zzxx-husky/50c5ad0cf56254dc0e01d7cb6b8389ad .

For the above gist example, if I directly use graphviz to convert it to png, graphviz throws me a segfault

```
libpath/shortest.c:324: triangulation failed
libpath/shortest.c:192: source point not in any triangle
Error: in routesplines, Pshortestpath failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I tried to add `rankdir=LR` at the beginning, that may help convert the dot to png successfully, but graphviz still complains a lot of `Warning: XXX -> YYY: head not inside head cluster clusterZZZ` and the png is ugly (DAG nodes may overlap with each other).

Finally, I have to **comment** out all the `rank=same` in the dot if I want to convert the dot to a nice png successfully. However, those large DAG nodes in the png require a lot of space to present their subgraphs and the large subgraphs look a mess.

At the end, I wonder whether my use of `rank=same` is not correct and how can I reduce the space for presenting a large subgraph. Thanks in advance.

**====== Updates at 20200810 ======**

To answer @sroush's question, what I want is that those large subgraphs can use less space to present their topologies compactly. Here is how a subgraph with 7 vertices is presented (the left one below). The subgraph edges are too long and bend weirdly. But I hope less space is used, like the right one below, which is more neat and compact. One may point out that the figure below looks smaller is because I removed all the edge label. I wonder whether it is possible to make the subgraph neat while the subgraph edges still carry their labels.

[image]
[image]

Comment: 1. If you install a newer version of Graphviz (2.44.1) the file you posted will run (quickly) to completion.  There are still many error messages, but no core dump.  2. I suggest capturing the error output & reporting this bug. 3. Would you provide an example of what you want the cluster to look like

Comment: Hi @sroush , nice to see you again in this question! I updated Graphviz to 2.44.1 and the new version did convert successfully. But if you take a look at the png, you will find some DAG nodes (especially those with large subgraphs) overlap with each other, which is not what I want. (The case is similar to using `rankdir=LR`) I have thought about reporting the bug but I don't know how to describe the problem correctly ... I will update the question description to answer your last question.

Answer (score 1):

Three possibilities - if you like any of them I'll post the input files. Coloring the edges would probably help.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the efforts! For the three possibilities, the 2nd one is NOT the one I want because that all vertices are organized in a line makes it hard to understand what the subgraph topology is. For the 1st one, I doubt it may be hard to understand the subgraph topo as well. For the 3rd one, its vertex layout is actually what my strategy is trying to do (divide `n` vertices into `n/2` layers and each layer contains 2 vertices)! But the subgraph edges in the 3rd one look wierd, i.e., the edges are not contained by the blue box.

Comment: `Coloring the edges would probably help`: I think maybe this is the solution: coloring the edges and add a legend indicating which color is for which label.